# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token< VM3419:1

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am creating a demo utilizing AJAX techniques. In my project, I use AJAX methods to get data from the server. But I get this error:

> " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token<  xhr.onreadystatechange @main.js"

**JS:**

```js
(function(){
 var xhr = null;
 if(window.ActiveXObject){
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 else{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

 xhr.open("GET","data/stuInfo.php",true);
 xhr.send();

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4){
   if(xhr.status == 200){
    var HTML = "";
    
    var data = eval("("+xhr.responseText + ")");
    
    for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){
     HTML += "<li><span>"+data[i].Code+"</span>";
     HTML += "<span>"+data[i].Name+"</span>";
     HTML += "<span>"+data[i].Score+"</span></li>";
    }
    document.getElementByID("stuInfo").innerHTML = HTML;
   }
  }
 };

 
})();
```

**PHP:**

```js
<?php
 header("Content-type:text/json");
 $stulist = array(
  array("Code" => "10101", "Name" => "刘真真", "Score" => "530"),
  array("Code" => "10102", "Name" => "张明基", "Score" => "460"),
  array("Code" => "10103", "Name" => "舒虎", "Score" => "660"),
  array("Code" => "10104", "Name" => "周小敏", "Score" => "500"),
  array("Code" => "10105", "Name" => "陆明明", "Score" => "300")
 );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are a couple things to change:**

1. It appears that the PHP code is not doing anything with the `$stulist`. Try using `echo` or `print` with the data in JSON format, like the updated example below demonstrates.
2. Instead of using `eval()` with the response text, you should be able to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) - i.e. `var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`, given that the header for content-type is `test/json. See the second code snippet below.
3. The call to `document.getElementById` has an uppercase `D` instead of a lowercase `d` at the end of the function name. Change it to a lowercase `d` to avoid an error.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/json");
$stulist = array(
    array("Code" => "10101", "Name" => "刘真真", "Score" => "530"),
    array("Code" => "10102", "Name" => "张明基", "Score" => "460"),
    array("Code" => "10103", "Name" => "舒虎", "Score" => "660"),
    array("Code" => "10104", "Name" => "周小敏", "Score" => "500"),
array("Code" => "10105", "Name" => "陆明明", "Score" => "300")
);
echo json_encode($stulist);
?>
```

**JS:**

```js
(function(){
 var xhr = null;
 if(window.ActiveXObject){
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 else{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
        //sample API request to get sample data in  JSON format - replace the second parameter with your endpoint "data/stuInfo.php"
     xhr.open("GET","http://elliott.andrewz.org/data/stuInfo.php",true);
 xhr.send();

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4){
   if(xhr.status == 200){
    var HTML = "";
    
    //use JSON.parse here instead of eval()
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    //reveal what that data object is:
    console.log('data: ',data);
              
    for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){
     HTML += "<li><span>"+data[i].Code+"</span>";
     HTML += "<span>"+data[i].Name+"</span>";
     HTML += "<span>"+data[i].Score+"</span></li>";
    }
    document.getElementById("stuInfo").innerHTML = HTML;
   }
  }
 };

 
})();
```

## Update

In a comment, you mention that you are still seeing the error. Have you tried using the network tab of your browser console to watch the AJAX request to see what the response code and body are? In the screenshot below, I am inspecting the AJAX request in this scenario in Google Chrome (which can be opened by pressing *F12* or *CTRL*+*SHIFT*+*i*). Mozilla Firefox, Safari and the latest versions of IE/Edge have similar consoles. I filtered to *XHR* requests and see that the [response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is `200`. If you see a different number (e.g. 400, 500) then there is likely an error finding the file or the code.

[image: inspecting the network tab of the browser console in Chrome]

Comment: Thank you very much.  When I use a `.json` file`: xhr.open("GET","test.json",true);`, the result is right. But when I use a .php file:xhr.open("GET","test.php",true);, it also comes the error info " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token< VM3419:1".